# How can i download a file from a private Amazon S3 bucket in a VB.net application?

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this vb.net application that needs to download a file that's in a private s3 bucket, i have both access and secret key already

Comment: There's no code example with visual basic, only C#

Comment: Add the C# code and we'll give you a hand translating it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html

In "Using the AWS SDK" section

Comment: Will you be able to help me?

Comment: You have to at least try. Copy the c# code into your module and see if you can alter the syntax to vb.net. It is quite easy.