# Can i convert this C# code into Visual basic?

Tags: c#, vb.net, amazon-s3

Got this from another post, i have two questions:

1 - Is this enough to download a s3 object?

2 - Can i convert into visual basic code?

```
    main()    
{
    string path = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX./latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EC2_WLMA_Permissions";
 
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                string result = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    dynamic metaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                    _awsAccessKeyId = metaData.AccessKeyId;
                    _awsSecretAccessKey = metaData.SecretAccessKey;
                }
}
 
SessionAWSCredentials tempCredentials =
                 GetTemporaryCredentials(_awsAccessKeyId, _awsSecretAccessKey);
 
private static SessionAWSCredentials GetTemporaryCredentials(
                    string accessKeyId, string secretAccessKeyId)
    {             
 
        AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient =
        new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(accessKeyId,
                                                 secretAccessKeyId);
        Console.WriteLine(stsClient.ToString());
        GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest =
                                         new GetSessionTokenRequest();
 
        getSessionTokenRequest.DurationSeconds = 7200; // seconds
        GetSessionTokenResponse sessionTokenResponse =
                      stsClient.GetSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);
 
        Console.WriteLine(sessionTokenResponse.ToString());
        Credentials credentials = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials;
        Console.WriteLine(credentials.ToString());
 
        SessionAWSCredentials sessionCredentials =
            new SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId,
                                      credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                                      credentials.SessionToken);
 
 
        return sessionCredentials;
    }
Get files from S3 using AmazonS3Client:
 
using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(tempCredentials,RegionEndpoint.USEast1))                        
    {
                    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
                    request.BucketName = "bucketName" + @"/" + "foldername";
                    request.Key = "Terms.docx";
                    GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);
                    response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("C:\\MyFile.docx");
    }
```

Obs: i already have the access key and secret key, i need to download a file from a s3 using a visual basic standalone application

Comment: https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/ or similar will give you a head start

Comment: Viewers note also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485837/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-a-private-amazon-s3-bucket-in-a-vb-net-applicatio

Comment: But this code will work the way it is? I can convert with some effort but i need to know if the code is valid or something is missing

Comment: Run it; make a new C# console project (look at where you got it from for clues to whether it's .net framework or core), paste it in, press play. C# and VB are practically the same language, with minor syntactical differences; we can help you fix errors. Don't let "it's C#" make you scream and run away; it would be wise to gain a passing acquantiance/ability to read C# anyway because a lot of the things you'll want to do in VB will probably have numerous C# examples but a relative paucity of VB ones

Answer (score 0):

Here's a leg-up; it's the code you posted, but arranged so it builds. Make a new .NET 472 console project, paste this over the top of the Program.cs file contents:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.SecurityToken;
using Amazon.SecurityToken.Model;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

namespace A
{
    class X
    {
        static string _awsAccessKeyId;
        static string _awsSecretAccessKey;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Main2();
            Main3();
        }

        static void Main2()
        {

            string path = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX./latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EC2_WLMA_Permissions";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            string result = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic metaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                _awsAccessKeyId = metaData.AccessKeyId;
                _awsSecretAccessKey = metaData.SecretAccessKey;
            }
        }
        static void Main3()
        {
            SessionAWSCredentials tempCredentials =
                 GetTemporaryCredentials(_awsAccessKeyId, _awsSecretAccessKey);

            using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(tempCredentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
                request.BucketName = "bucketName" + @"/" + "foldername";
                request.Key = "Terms.docx";
                GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);
                response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("C:\\MyFile.docx");
            }
        }

        private static SessionAWSCredentials GetTemporaryCredentials(
                            string accessKeyId, string secretAccessKeyId)
        {

            AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient =
            new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(accessKeyId,
                                                     secretAccessKeyId);
            Console.WriteLine(stsClient.ToString());
            GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest =
                                             new GetSessionTokenRequest();

            getSessionTokenRequest.DurationSeconds = 7200; // seconds
            GetSessionTokenResponse sessionTokenResponse =
                          stsClient.GetSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);

            Console.WriteLine(sessionTokenResponse.ToString());
            Credentials credentials = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials;
            Console.WriteLine(credentials.ToString());

            SessionAWSCredentials sessionCredentials =
                new SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId,
                                          credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                                          credentials.SessionToken);


            return sessionCredentials;
        }
    }
}
```

Install these NuGets:

[image]

Edit the IP, secrets etc into it and run it/check it does what you want.. Then you can set about converting it to VB and polishing it up

Edit:

And here's the result of running iCsharpCode's VS extension converter on the C#, if C# is anathema :D :

```
Option Strict Off

Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Amazon.Runtime
Imports Amazon.SecurityToken
Imports Amazon.SecurityToken.Model
Imports Amazon.S3
Imports Amazon
Imports Amazon.S3.Model



Namespace A
    Public Module X
        Private _awsAccessKeyId As String
        Private _awsSecretAccessKey As String

        Public Sub Main()
            Call Main2()
            Call Main3()
        End Sub

        Private Sub Main2()
            Dim path = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX./latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EC2_WLMA_Permissions"
            Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(path), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Method = "GET"
            request.ContentType = "application/json"
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Dim result = String.Empty

            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                result = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Dim metaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result)
                _awsAccessKeyId = metaData.AccessKeyId
                _awsSecretAccessKey = metaData.SecretAccessKey
            End Using
        End Sub

        Private Sub Main3()
            Dim tempCredentials = GetTemporaryCredentials(_awsAccessKeyId, _awsSecretAccessKey)

            Using client As IAmazonS3 = New AmazonS3Client(tempCredentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1)
                Dim request As GetObjectRequest = New GetObjectRequest()
                request.BucketName = "bucketName" & "/" & "foldername"
                request.Key = "Terms.docx"
                Dim response = client.GetObject(request)
                response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("C:\MyFile.docx")
            End Using
        End Sub

        Private Function GetTemporaryCredentials(ByVal accessKeyId As String, ByVal secretAccessKeyId As String) As SessionAWSCredentials
            Dim stsClient As AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient = New AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(accessKeyId, secretAccessKeyId)
            Console.WriteLine(stsClient.ToString())
            Dim getSessionTokenRequest As GetSessionTokenRequest = New GetSessionTokenRequest()
            getSessionTokenRequest.DurationSeconds = 7200 ' seconds
            Dim sessionTokenResponse = stsClient.GetSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest)
            Console.WriteLine(sessionTokenResponse.ToString())
            Dim credentials = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials
            Console.WriteLine(credentials.ToString())
            Dim sessionCredentials As SessionAWSCredentials = New SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId, credentials.SecretAccessKey, credentials.SessionToken)
            Return sessionCredentials
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: God bless you, for real